# Adding annotated values in xmgrace using batch mode

Tags: string, plot, annotations

I need some help adding a series of annotated string values to my xy plot in Grace-5.1.22 when using a batch script to plot the graph.

I have two columns of data: a series of x values and a series of y values, and then a third column containing a number for each data point. If I want to plot all numbers in the z column as annotated values then I am able to import the data into grace using the command:

BLOCK XYZ "1:2:3"

S0 AVALUE ON

S0 AVALUE TYPE "Z"

However, since where data points are bunched together the annotations are not clear, I don't want to display the annotation on EVERY point and therefore have replaced some values in the z column with "" to leave the corresponding annotation blank. This means that the 3rd column is now a string and the above commands will not work.

This website http://plasma-gate.weizmann.ac.il/Xmgr/doc/commands.html suggests that I should be able to import the data as:

BLOCK XYSTRING "1:2:3"

However, unfortunately this type was removed from versions 5.0.3 onwards http://plasma-gate.weizmann.ac.il/Grace/doc/CHANGES.html

Instead the documentation now says that "any set type now may have an additional column of text strings associated" however the command:

BLOCK XY "1:2:3"

does not load any data giving the error: "Too many columns scanned in column string".

I am able to import string type annotated values into xy data using the GUI by:

Data>>Import>>ASCII>>"filename.dat">>"load as BLOCK DATA">>"strings from column 3"

however since I would like to plot the same graph many times for different data sets I would like a way of automating this process and not using the GUI.

Sorry for the for the long question but I would be very grateful if anyone could help me.

Answer (score 2):

*I know it's old but I had the same question and after 3 hours of experimenting, I found a solution. Therefore I post it for future reference (since no answer currently exists elsewhere online).*

If your "filename.dat" has the content format of (x y "string") or (x y z) then you can add to your batch file the following to read it and add the annotations:

```
READ XY "filename.dat"
s0 line type 1
s0 line linewidth 1
s0 line color 1
# Enable annotations
s0 avalue on
# Select type: 0=None,4=String,5=Z
s0 avalue type 5
s0 avalue color 1
s0 avalue char size 1.0000
s0 avalue offset 0.000000 , 0.000000
```

If you want to see more options for batch files, you can make a plot interactively with the gui and then save it as an .agr file. If you open this with a text editor, you have all the available commands there.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a direct answer to your question but it may give you a hint.
I ran accross the same error message with the following syntax :

```
gracebat -graph 0 -settype bardy -block mydatafile -bxy 0:5:6:2
```

(the last column intended to be the optional string column)

And this one proved to be the right one :

```
gracebat -graph 0 -settype bardy -block mydatafile -bxy 0:5:6:{2}
```

So I guess you need to add curly braces.

Comment: Please leave this as a comment instead.